# Memory leak with Libusb

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libusb-1.0

I've been porting a library from Linux to Windows, and while debugging i found out that on Windows (at least on my machine) hotplug functionality is not supported.

So, I've decided to create a workaround instead of heavily modifying the library, i took the challenge of emulating hotplug events.

I've nearly completed my program, but I've found that i leak memory (VS2015 resources monitor shows steady increase of RAM usage).
I've narrowed down to hm_monitor loop, but I can't find where the error is.
Diagnostic Tools showed me that memory leak originates in Libusb-dll.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oafc9.jpg)

```
int delete_device(libusb_device* dev, libusb_device** list, size_t* count) {
    libusb_unref_device(dev);
    size_t i;
    int res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *count; i++)
        if (list[i] == dev) {
            list[i] = list[(*count) - 1];
            list[*count] = 0;
            (*count)--;
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    return res;
}

int add_device(libusb_device* dev, libusb_device** list, size_t* count) {
    libusb_ref_device(dev);
    if (*count >= MAX_DEVICES)
        return 0;
    list[*count] = dev;
    (*count)++;
    return 1;
}

thrd_start_t hm_monitor(void* data) {
    int r; //for return values
    size_t i; //user for for loops
    ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list
    hm_data_t d = (hm_data_t)data;
    libusb_device *old_devs[MAX_DEVICES] = { 0 };
    size_t old_count = 0;
    libusb_device **devs; //pointer to pointer of device, used to retrieve a list of devices

    //while hm_stop is not called
    while (!d->stop) {
        //getting connected device list
        cnt = libusb_get_device_list(d->ctx, &devs);
        if (cnt < 0) {
            stop_thread(-1);//end monitor prematurely because error
        }

        //loop devs to find new devices
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
            int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(devs[i], &desc);
            if (r < 0) //if device descriptor is unaccessable
                continue; //ignore it
            if (desc.idVendor == 0 || desc.idProduct == 0) //ghost device
                continue; //ignore it;
            if (!find_device(devs[i], old_devs, old_count)) { //if the device was just connected
                //add device to the old_devs
                r = add_device(devs[i], old_devs, &old_count);
                if (!r)  //if we could not add a device
                    stop_thread(-6);
                //Call on_arrived callbacks
                int c;
                for (c = 0; c < hm_state.cb_count; c++) {
                    if (hm_state.callbacks[c].fn && (hm_state.callbacks[c].dev_class == (int)desc.bDeviceClass || hm_state.callbacks[c].dev_class == -1)
                        && (hm_state.callbacks[c].vendor_id == (int)desc.idVendor || hm_state.callbacks[c].vendor_id == -1)
                        && (hm_state.callbacks[c].product_id == (int)desc.idProduct || hm_state.callbacks[c].product_id == -1))
                        if (hm_state.callbacks[c].events | LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED)
                            hm_state.callbacks[c].fn(d->ctx, devs[i], LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED, data);
                }

            }
        }


        for (i = 0; i < old_count; i++) {
            struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
            r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(old_devs[i], &desc);
            if (r < 0) // if somehow a device like this ended up in old_dev, delete it
            {
                delete_device(old_devs[i], old_devs, &old_count);
                continue;
            }
            if (desc.idVendor == 0 || desc.idProduct == 0)
            {
                delete_device(old_devs[i], old_devs, &old_count);
                continue;
            }
            if (!find_device(old_devs[i], devs, cnt)) {
                int c;
                for (c = 0; c < hm_state.cb_count; c++) {

                    if (hm_state.callbacks[c].fn && (hm_state.callbacks[c].dev_class == (int)desc.bDeviceClass || hm_state.callbacks[c].dev_class == -1)
                        && (hm_state.callbacks[c].vendor_id == (int)desc.idVendor || hm_state.callbacks[c].vendor_id == -1)
                        && (hm_state.callbacks[c].product_id == (int)desc.idProduct || hm_state.callbacks[c].product_id == -1))
                        if (hm_state.callbacks[c].events | LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT)
                            hm_state.callbacks[c].fn(d->ctx, old_devs[i], LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT, data);
                }
                //remove device from the list
                delete_device(old_devs[i], old_devs, &old_count);
            }
        }


        libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, do not unref devices becuase we unref them when they leave.

    }//END LOOP HERE

}
```

Source listing:
[gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/vharabar/kibusb_hotplug_emulaton/tree/master).

Edit: added relevant code to the question.

Comment: can you add the code you think is responsible (as slimmed down as possible) to your question?

Comment: I've added the code you asked to the question.

Comment: You should add the code that actually allocates memory. It is probably done somewhere in the library that populates structures in this code. For example, does struct libsub_device_descriptor contain any pointers to allocated memory? If yes, who is responsible for releasing it?

Comment: @VictorHavin well you see, i've tested multiple parts of the code, and it seems the leak only occurs when i use libusb_un/ref_device(), And i'm sure that my program does not spam them because i've tested this with console output. It seems that having some devices referenced and calling libusb_get_device_list generates garbage. I will look into libusb source code (which is not hard t find, and posting here will clutter the post) but it wil take me a lot of time.

Comment: @FanciestBanana: You should find memory allocators originated from the code you suspect is leaky. You can do it with debugger. Just set a bnreakpoint in libusb_get_device_list generates. After you heat it, set another breakpoint in HeapAlloc. When you exit HeapAlloc, save the address. Se if this address got deallocated in the end of the run. If not - this is your leak. I recommend using Windbg. The !heap extension will help you a lot. You can also use a memory debugger (like Valgrind).

Comment: The search for the memory leak is too tedious for it's benefit, so i've switched to searching a libusb implementation that actually supports hotplug. I've already found several candidates and i will post an answer to my post after some testing.